# Problem with typing "^" in Texmaker?

Tags: texmaker, windows

I am using [Texmaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/) for making documents in Latex. However for some reason I am not able to type the symbol "^". I am able to type other symbols which require you to hold SHIFT + {other key}, such as !, @, #, $, %, & and *, using the numbers 1 to 5 and 7 to 9. However, when I try to do the same with 6, which should produce a ^, I get nothing.  I have to press and hold for a while before I can get the symbol typed. Note that I can still type "^" in other programs (such Microsoft Word) normally (without holding the keys for sometime).

My temporary solution is to type it in another program (often a web browser) and copy out of it. But I would expect that you would be able to type it in Texmaker itself.

Do other people have the same issue, or does anyone know how to resolve this?

**Edit with some extra system info**
OS: Windows 7 enterprise
Texmaker version: 4.0.2

**Edit 2**
Just updated Texmaker to version 4.1.1 and the issue no longer occurs/I am able to type "^" via Shift + 6.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.  This is a pretty weird problem.  Are there any other keys that aren't typing? Does the key combination work in another editor?

Comment: i'm not a texmaker user, so can't help with the problem directly. but there's an alternative -- if you can't (for whatever reason) type `^`, you can type `\sp` instead.  saves cutting and pasting from another program.

Comment: Isn't this just because you have to press space afterwards (to avoid doing "²" instead of "^2")?

Comment: Did you use `Shift+6` as a shortcut in `Options`-->`Configure`->`Shortcuts`. BTW Are you using latest [Jul 29 2013](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html) version of TeXmaker, May be read "Installing the ibus-qt package is recommended to avoid some trouble with accentued characters on some linux distributions (for Qt4 versions only)" might help.

Comment: Downvoters: Please care to explain WHY ?

Comment: Is the `windows` tag correct? Which OS and Texmaker version do you have? (Not sure if it is relevant, but I don't think the extra information hurts.)

Comment: @MikaelÖhman, no I have tried pressing other keys after SHIFT+6 but does not work. And like Torbjørn T. suggested I have added some more system information, if that might help.

Comment: If nothing works even with the latest 4.0.3 version, the best thing would be to capture a video shot and post it at [TeXmaker issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/texmaker/issues/list), the author is quite responsive

Comment: Nothing has been posted on the official Texmaker issue tracker and no shot has been published.

Comment: If the problem still persists you can post at [texmaker issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/texmaker/issues/list) or if you found a solution please nominate to reopen the post and community will reopen by voting.

Comment: I just tied a few things again in 4.0.2 and was still not able to type "^" with Shift + 6, but I did found a shortcut in the config settings (Ctrl + Shift + U) which types "^{•}". After this I also upgraded to 4.1.1 and I was able to type "^" using Shift + 6, however the shortcut for "^{•}" does no longer work, but that is another issue and is not that important.